# Record Type Personal Settings through Apex

Tags: apex, record-type

When creating users I would like to programmatically select that the default record types be selected for each object for all users.

I really dislike that I have to log in as user and check each box when on-boarding.

Is this possible?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean. You can set default record types for each object by profile. But if you provide more context we might be able to help.

Comment: I have default record type for all users. When I create a new user, by default they are asked to select which record type they want to use unless they have "Record Type Selection" Select Default as ''True". This is in setup under "My Personal Information > Record Type Selection" I want to check this box programatically.

Comment: Why not simply remove all of the non-default record types from your Profiles? Then the users will never be faced with a selection screen.

Comment: Don't think you can programmatically achieve what you are looking for. As far as I could search, there does not seem to be any support available to "update" any other User's personal information using api.